# "Other Contacts" in Google API is able to retrive in PHP GooglePeople

Tags: php, gmail-api, google-contacts-api

When I am using https://github.com/rapidwebltd/php-google-people-api, I am able to get **My Contacts** but not **Other Contacts**.

```
$refreshToken = $googleOAuth2Handler->getRefreshToken($_GET["code"]);

$people = new GooglePeople($googleOAuth2Handler);
$i=0;
// Retrieval all contacts
foreach($people->all() as $contact) {
            
    if ($contact->names) {              
            
        echo $contact->names[0]->displayName."<br />";
    }
    if ($contact->phoneNumbers) {
         echo $contact->phoneNumbers[0]->value."<br /><br />";
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Hi
I found it after One day research.Here is the code for PHP in order to access google people API (Other Contacts):**

```
1- scope : $client->addScope(Google_Service_PeopleService::CONTACTS_OTHER_READONLY);
2- code :
$optParams = array(
  'pageSize' => 10, //number of contact return
  'readMask' => 'emailAddresses',
);

$results = $service->otherContacts->listOtherContacts($optParams);
if (count($results->getOtherContacts()) == 0) {
  print "No connections found.\n";
} else {
  print "Other Contact list:"; echo "<br>";
  $count=0;
  foreach ($results->getotherContacts() as $person) {
      
    if (count($person->getemailAddresses()) == 0) {
      print "No names found for this connection\n";
    } else {  
      $emailAddresses = $person->getemailAddresses();
      $email = $emailAddresses[$count];
      $contactmail[$count]=$email->getvalue(); 
      echo $count;echo " -"; echo $contactmail[$count];
      echo "<br>";
    }
  }
 }
```